# Why is this if statement failing to evaluate the condition?

Tags: kdb

I deal with the following situation:

```
{[x;y]first{[x;y] 
              if[not null first ss[x;raze string[y],"="];
              ind:ss[x;raze string[y],"="];
              pt1:(first ind)#x;
              pt2:((first ind)+count[raze string[y],"="]) _ x;
              pt2:(first ss[pt2;"|"]) _ pt2;
              x:pt1,(string[y],"=test_TAG_",string[.z.P]),pt2];
              :x
           }\[y;x]}[fields;]each a;
```

So what the code does is:

```
1. Takes each string a in the form of a fix message "TAG=value|TAG2=value2 ..."
2. Takes variable fields which contains either 1, 2, 3 ...n symbols. 
3. Searches through the string fro the field, finds the index adds value after "=". 
4. [...] keeps doing that until all the values in fields have been depleted
```

The problem is that the if statement does not check the value. If it is `0b` or `1b` it keeps going and executes `ind:ss[x;raze string[y],"="]` no matter what. Why is that happening?

Comment: Just as a note for parsing key value pairs you can use `0:`, the process is explained on the [Kx wiki](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#key-value-pairs).

Comment: thanks Thomas! however, this is part of an update statement. using `0:` would require me to convert to a dictionary, change the value and then change back ti fix messages.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting 0b in If condition? Try printing the condition output using 0N! and also adding some show statements after 'if' will help to check whether next statements are getting executed or not for false case.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though

```
first {}\[]
```

has actually caused your function to return the initial result. 
`Scan` will itirate through each field but `first` will discard these and return only the first iteration on the string.

Using `over` in the below syntax will allow you perform this operation and return the final version of the string.

```
f
{[x;y]{[x;y]
              if[not null first ss[x;raze string[y],"="];
              ind:ss[x;raze string[y],"="];
              pt1:(first ind)#x;
              pt2:((first ind)+count[raze string[y],"="]) _ x;
              pt2:(first ss[pt2;"|"]) _ pt2;
              x:pt1,(string[y],"=test_TAG_",string[.z.P]),pt2];
              :x
           }/[y;x]}
q)a
"1=abc|3=44.4|9=4000"
"1=xyz|3=55.5|5=99|9=2000"
q)fields:1 3 99
q)r:f[fields] each a
q)r
"1=test_TAG_2018.11.06D10:18:14.574411000|3=test_TAG_2018.11.06D10:18:14.574431000|9=4000"
"1=test_TAG_2018.11.06D10:18:14.574447000|3=test_TAG_2018.11.06D10:18:14.574458000|5=99|9=2000"
```

Based off these samples the function seems to be correctly skipping over the undefined tag (e.g the `99` tag in the above example). If you could provide an example where this isn't the case maybe that could be checked.

Furthermore there are just a few bugs with regards tag matching>

1) Partial tags will be matched, in that if a search for 3 were carried out, any tag ending with 3 will cause a match.

```
q)a:("1=abc|3=44.4|9=4000";"1=xyz|3=55.5|5=99|9=2000";"1=jkl|33=50|66=0")
q)f[fields] each a
"1=test_TAG_2018.11.06D11:51:09.469637000|3=test_TAG_2018.11.06D11:51:09.469653000|9=4000"
"1=test_TAG_2018.11.06D11:51:09.469666000|3=test_TAG_2018.11.06D11:51:09.469674000|5=99|9=2000"
"1=test_TAG_2018.11.06D11:51:09.469685000|33=test_TAG_2018.11.06D11:51:09.469694000|66=0"
```

2) Also, if the matched tag is in the final section and there is not a closing `|`, the code will not work properly. This is dependent of course on the structure of the message.

```
q)f[3 9] "1=abc|3=44.4|9=4000"
{[x;y]
...
           }
'type
_
0N
"4000"
```

It should be noted that while keeping it as a string will be initially more efficient, if there are more than a couple of fields the use of `0:` to parse the key value pairs would be faster, and will prevent any of the afforementioned edge cases from occuring.